# org.xml.sax.SAXException: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created

Tags: java, xml, xslt, sax

I picked up an old script that previous run on linux server a while ago using xalan jar 2.6.0. Now I have download xalan 2.7.2 on aws server.  Following is the command:

java -Xmx3036m -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/ec2-user/Search_Aids/xalan-jar/xalan-j_2_7_2/xalan.jar:/home/ec2-user/Search_Aids/xalan-jar/xalan-j_2_7_2/xalan.jar/xalan-j_2_7_2/xercesImpl.jar:/home/ec2-user/Search_Aids/xalan-jar/xalan-j_2_7_2/xml-apis.jar org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -in dummy.xml -xsl /home/ec2-user/Search_Aids/entry.xsl -out entry.xml -FLAVOR s2s=SAX -param dinput d2021.xml -param qinput q2021.xml  -param prev_index_mapping previdxrefs.xml

And I got following error message:
(Location of error unknown)org.xml.sax.SAXException: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created

(Location of error unknown)XSLT Error (javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException): getAssociatedStylesheets failed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: getAssociatedStylesheets failed
at org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process.doExit(Process.java:1155)
at org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process.main(Process.java:1128)

I am not a java developer and not familiar with xalan.  But the error sounds like xalan can not recognize global java class SAXParser.  I have no idea what this option "-FLAVOR s2s=SAX" does.  Remove that option will send the same error message.

Any help and suggestions would be appreciated.

Jianhua

Comment: Why did you add the "saxon" tag?

Comment: Try running with the system property `-Djaxp.debug=1` to provide diagnostics on JAXP dynamic loading.

Comment: Michael, I inherited the old script and no idea why need "saxon" tag.  It seems that tag is useless.  Anyway,  Added the debug tag I got following message
JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
(Location of error unknown)org.xml.sax.SAXException: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created
JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory

(Location of error unknown)XSLT Error ...

Comment: Michael, thanks for your help.

Comment: Change " -Xbootclasspath/a:" with "-classpath " seems getting program running but got this error message: SystemId Unknown; Line #-1; Column #-1; Premature end of file.

Comment: Problem solved.  Create a valid dummy.xml file and program runs.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Replace `-Xbootclasspath/a:` with `-classpath` and use a valid `dummy.xml` file.